# Laravel sync return SQLSTATE[42S22]

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to save ids of 2 models with sync method but i get this error:

> message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'cable_core_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `closure_cores`
>   (`cable_core_id`, `core_id`) values (20, 28))"

## Screenshot

This is the data that i sent to back-end

[image: one]

#### models

`TitikClosur`

```
class TitikClosur extends Model
{
    public function cores(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(CableCore::class, 'closure_cores', 'core_id');
    }
}
```

`CableCore`

```
class CableCore extends Model
{
    public function closures(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(TitikClosur::class, 'closure_cores', 'closure_id');
    }
}
```

#### Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $titik = new TitikClosur;
  //...
  $titik->save();
  $titik->cores()->sync($request->cores, false);
  return....
}
```

#### Schema

This is how my table for saving ids looks like

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('closure_cores', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('core_id');
            $table->foreignId('closure_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('closure_cores', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('core_id')->references('id')->on('cable_cores')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('closure_id')->references('id')->on('titik_closurs')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

I have changed my model codes like this:

`TitikClosur`

```
public function cores(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(CableCore::class, 'closure_cores', 'core_id', 'closure_id');
}
```

`CableCore`

```
public function closures(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(TitikClosur::class, 'closure_cores', 'closure_id', 'core_id');
}
```

Now I'm getting this error

> message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot
>   add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`gis-web`.`closure_cores`, CONSTRAINT `closure_cores_core_id_foreign`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`core_id`) REFERENCES `cable_cores` (`id`)) (SQL: insert
>   into `closure_cores` (`closure_id`, `core_id`) values (20, 34))"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When not otherwise instructed laravel expects the name of the foreign key on a pivot table to be the singular of the table name with _id tacked on to the end. You have made a mistake in your belongsToMany statement. You have switched the keys in your two statements, the relation returned by cores() thinks that core_id refers to the id of the TitikClosur and assumes that the CableCore model must have the key cable_core_id, but can not find it in the table. Furthermore the two relation functions in the two models do not have any way to share information. So really you should be doing:

```php
class TitikClosur extends Model
{
    public function cores(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(CableCore::class, 'closure_cores', 'closure_id', 'core_id');
    }
}
```

and

```php
class CableCore extends Model
{
    public function closures(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(TitikClosur::class, 'closure_cores', 'core_id', 'closure_id');
    }
}
```

In response to your update:

The second error usually means that there is no CableCore with an id of 34 in your database.